# Let ASP.NET Core 8 Web API accept SOAP like XML as input

Tags: web-services, soap, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-8

I am trying to write an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that accepts a SOAP XML, and returns a XML response.

I created this controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public IActionResult Get(TestThing inputXml)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

And added XML formatters to the `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Here is my request class:

```
[XmlRoot("TestThing", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/")]
public partial class TestThing
{
    public string? Header { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine if I am using this XML as input

```
<TestThing xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
    <Header>sdfs sdfsd sdfsdfs sdfsdf</Header>
</TestThing>
```

The problem is that according the documentation, the XML the server is going to receive is this one:

```
<soapenv:ETestThing xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>sdfs sdfsd sdfsdfs sdfsdf</soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:ETestThing>
```

And when I try to send that xml I got this error:

> An error occurred while deserializing input data

Yep the `soapenv:` part seems to be a bit of a problem.

What should I do so that the data could be correctly deserialized? I am bit puzzled: I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2r7z4W30AE and it does not seem to require extra steps to accept the xml input (actually I got an extra `[Consumes("application/xml")]` that the guy did not need to run its code) but in my case it seems like something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand how the guy on the tutorial I indicated in the original question got its code to work, but I found I way to get my code working.

1. I used this tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022 to generate the envelope tags from an example XML file that I had.

In case the link above stops working: just from Visual Studio do Edit/Paste Special/Paste Xml as Classes

I noticed that the classes generated this way had some extra attributes that I guess took care of my missing "soapenv" issues.

2. Also to generate the body I used the xsd tool (fortunately I had the xsd files)

Putting those 2 things together got my app working.

Answer (score 0):

You xml is `<soapenv:ETestThing` instead of `<soapenv:TestThing`, so the corresponding model design should change to:

```
[XmlRoot("ETestThing", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/")]
```

Comment: Corrected, still the same problem

Comment: Hi @Art, does your model contain any other property? Be sure the namespace the soap send are the same with the Namespace you define in the model. And could you pls share more detailed error message?

Comment: The error was Literally "An error occurred while deserializing input data". I would have loved it, if I had got a more detailed error, but unlucklily that was not the case. The model was this thin, because I was trying with a simple model to troubleshoot an issue I had with the complete one

Comment: Hi @Art, if though, I suggest you can share a minimal repo which can reproduce you issue.